# What is the difference between function call and goto &NAME in Perl?

Tags: perl, goto, function-call

I'm reading Perl which is quite interesting. But while reading [goto from here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_goto_statement.htm) in Perl I got a doubt.

I know that goto statement has three types.

> goto LABEL.
>
> goto EXPR.
>
> goto &NAME.

But in this three types, what is the use of third one `goto &NAME`?
This is also seems to be like a function call.
Then,

1. What is the real difference between `goto &NAME` and normal `function call` in Perl?
2. When we use goto &NAME?

Can anyone please explain with example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It says in the [goto](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html) page

> The `goto &NAME` form is quite different from the other forms of
>               `goto`. In fact, it isn't a goto in the normal sense at all, and
>               doesn't have the stigma associated with other gotos.

Then follows the answer to your question

> Instead, it
>               exits the current subroutine (losing any changes set by `local()`)
>               and immediately calls in its place the named subroutine using the
>               current value of `@_`.

With a normal function call the execution continues on the next line after the function exits.

The rest of that paragraph is well worth reading as well, and answers your second question

> This is used by `AUTOLOAD` subroutines that wish to load another subroutine and then pretend that the other subroutine had been called in the first place (except that any modifications to `@_` in the current subroutine are propagated to the other subroutine.) After the `goto`, not even `caller` will be able to tell that this routine was called first.

---

A basic example. With a subroutine `deeper` defined somewhere, compare

```
sub func_top {
    deeper( @_ );  # pass its own arguments

    # The rest of the code here runs after deeper() returns
}
```

with

```
sub func_top {        
    goto &deeper;  # @_ is passed to it, as it is at this point

    # Control never returns here  
}
```

At the statement `goto &deeper` the sub `func_top` is exited. So after `deeper` completes, the control returns to after the `func_top` call.
In a sense, `func_top` is replaced by `deeper`.

Trying to pass arguments with `goto &func` results in errors, even just for `goto &deeper()`.

Comment: @Ganapathy  I added a basic example -- does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your example, I easily understood from your example

Comment: @Ganapathy Kindly consider accepting the answer then.