# How to conditionally import functions from another module and export them to the local namespace

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-exporter

Assume I have a module named `Local` that exports a subroutine `subLocal` via the `%EXPORT_TAGS` interface.

This module is closely related to another module named `Remote` that defines subroutines the user of `Local` might want to import.

There are two requirements I would like to have:

1. Module `Local` should import the subroutines defined in `Remote` only if the user of module `Local` is importing a subroutine defined in `Remote` (either by explicitly naming the export or by using a specific export tag)
2. When a subroutine from `Remote` is imported into `Local`, the user of module `Local` should be able to refer to that subroutine as if it is in his local namespace (the same behavior you would get when referring to a subroutine defined in `Local`).

I've only found a (hacky) solution for req. 2 by adding an entry in the symbol table, but this **always** occurs -- regardless if the user of `Local` actually needs the subroutines in `Remote`. According to perldoc, this pointlessly "pollutes" the namespace.

So at what point during compilation or runtime should I be trying to import the subroutines from `Remote`? And how do I actually import them in such a way that they appear in the local namespace?

This is my current approach. Module `Local`:

```
package Local;

use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN
{
  require Exporter;

  our @ISA = qw| Exporter |;

  our @EXPORT_LOCAL  = qw| subLocal |; 
  our @EXPORT_REMOTE = qw| subRemote |;

  our @EXPORT_OK   = ( @EXPORT_LOCAL, @EXPORT_REMOTE );
  our %EXPORT_TAGS = 
    ( all => \@EXPORT_OK, local => \@EXPORT_LOCAL, remote => \@EXPORT_REMOTE );

  *subRemote  = \&Remote::subRemote; # <-- can I do this conditionally somewhere? 
                                     # <-- and is there a better way to put this function in the user's local namespace?
}

use Remote; # <-- can I do this conditionally somewhere?

sub subLocal { return "(local)" }

1;
```

And module `Remote`:

```
package Remote;

use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN
{
  require Exporter;

  our @ISA = qw| Exporter |;

  our @EXPORT_REMOTE = qw| subRemote |;

  our @EXPORT_OK   = ( @EXPORT_REMOTE );
  our %EXPORT_TAGS = 
    ( all => \@EXPORT_OK, remote => \@EXPORT_REMOTE );
}

sub subRemote { return "(remote)" }

1;
```

Comment: This sounds like a circular definition to me. It reads as if you want to **1)** Import into `Local` the identifiers that are imported by `main` from `Remote` and **2)** Import into `main` the identifiers that are imported by `Local` from `Remote`. Is that correct? If so then it sounds like terrible design, and I think you need to give an example.

Comment: You probably want to implement your own `import`.

Comment: You won't be able to use Exporter. You'll need to implement your own `import`, or maybe one of the other export management modules can help.

Comment: @Borodin no, I'm only trying to achieve your statement **2)**. but with the added requirement of making that import conditional

Comment: @ardnew: Conditional on what? And what was your item **1** about? Don't you need that? A well-written example really would help hugely.

Comment: @ardnew: It really sounds like your `Local` should be a *class* that *subclasses* `Remote`. That way you don't need to worry about any imports at all, and Perl will find  the method wherever it is defined.

Comment: @Borodin the condition being "either by explicitly naming the export or by using a specific export tag". e.g. if the user writes `use Local qw| subRemote |;`, then `subRemote` (which is defined in `Remote`) should be imported and referenced as simply as `subRemote` instead of `Remote::subRemote`

Comment: @ardnew: Okay, firstly you don't need to import `Remote::subRemote` into `Local` at all; the code in `Local` can import the symbol into `main` without there being a copy in the `Local` package. And, as I said, this is a case for object-oriented design, where Perl will work everything out for you. are you up for that?

Comment: I suppose using inheritance is the proper design for this, I'm just entirely unfamiliar with OO in perl. I want to play around with a custom `sub import` first to see if I can achieve what I'm intending, sorry for the confusion

Comment: To be honest, I think the best solution of all for you is to forget about polluting your namespaces! You aren't planning on having hundreds of subroutines are you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to import subs into Local subs that Local is asked to export? Might as well place them directly into the right module instead of Local!

Either way, you won't be able to use (just) Exporter. There might an existing alternative to Exporter you could use. Otherwise, you'll need to write your own `import`.

Local.pm:

```
package Local;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp         qw( croak );
use Exporter     qw( );
use Import::Into qw( );
use Remote       qw( );

my @export_ok_local  = qw( subLocal );
my @export_ok_remote = qw( subRemote );
my @export_ok_all    = ( @export_ok_local, @export_ok_remote );

my %export_tags = (
   ':ALL'     => \@export_ok_all,
   ':DEFAULT' => [],
   ':local'   => \@export_ok_local,
   ':remote'  => \@export_ok_remote,
);

our @EXPORT_OK = @export_ok_local;

sub import {
   my $class = shift;
   my $target = caller;

   my @imports =
      map {
         !/^:/
            ? $_
            : !$export_tags{$_}
               ? croak("\"$_\" isn't a recognized tag")
               : @{ $export_tags{$_} }
      }
         @_;

   my %imports = map { $_ => 1 } @imports;

   my @local  = grep { $imports{$_} } @export_ok_local;
   my @remote = grep { $imports{$_} } @export_ok_remote;

   delete @imports{ @local, @remote };
   my @unknown = keys(%imports);
   croak("Not exported by ".__PACKAGE__.": @unknown\n") if @unknown;

   Remote->import::into($target, @remote);

   @_ = ( $class, @local );
   goto &Exporter::import;
}

sub subLocal { print("subLocal\n"); }

1;
```

Remote.pm:

```
package Remote;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( subRemote );

sub subRemote { print("subRemote\n"); }

1;
```

Test:

```
$ perl -e'
    use Local qw( subLocal subRemote );
    subLocal();
    subRemote();
'
subLocal
subRemote
```

```
$ perl -e'
    use Local qw( :ALL );
    subLocal();
    subRemote();
'
subLocal
subRemote
```

---

It's far simpler to simply import everything you want to export.

```
package Local;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );    

my ( @EXPORT_LOCAL, @EXPORT_REMOTE );
BEGIN {
  @EXPORT_LOCAL  = qw| subLocal |; 
  @EXPORT_REMOTE = qw| subRemote |;

  our @EXPORT_OK = ( @EXPORT_LOCAL, @EXPORT_REMOTE );

  our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    ALL    => \@EXPORT_OK,
    local  => \@EXPORT_LOCAL,
    remote => \@EXPORT_REMOTE,
  );
}

use Remote @EXPORT_REMOTE;

sub subLocal { ... }

1;
```

Comment: this is absolutely what I was imagining in my head, and probably answers the question best, but I think I have to agree with everyone suggesting it's a bit of a silly design

Comment: Not at all. It's common for modules to export stuff found in other modules. It's just that go about it by importing it first. Then it becomes a trivial use of Exporter (as shown at the bottom of my answer).

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I think that the confusion you will create by messing with `import` is probably more of a problem than the namespace pollution in the first place, which is only an issue if you choose identifiers that clash with the imported ones

Here's an example using object-oriented design, which doesn't use `import` at all and there is zero namespace pollution. You don't even have to say in the main program which methods you will use

#### Remote.pm

```
use 5.010;

package Remote;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    my $self = bless {}, $class;
}

sub subRemote {
    say "I am subRemote";
}

1;
```

#### Local.pm

```
use 5.010;

package Local;

use base 'Remote';

sub new {
  my $class = shift;

  my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@_);
}

sub subLocal {
    say "I am subLocal";
}

1;
```

#### main.pl

```
use 5.010;

use Local;

my $obj = Local->new;

$obj->subLocal;
$obj->subRemote;
```

#### output

```
I am subLocal
I am subRemote
```

Answer (score 1):

I take the question to be: That the caller of `Local` can require `subRemote` in its import list, but if it doesn't then the symbol isn't pushed into the caller's namespace.

I also assume that `Local` should not import from `Remote` at all unless the caller of `Local` requires some of `Remote`'s subs in its import list.

Then write your own `sub import`.  The list supplied by the caller are arguments passed to `import`, following the first argument which is `__PACKAGE__` (in this case `Local`).

Then in your `import` you can check whether `subRemote` is asked for. If it is, `require` the package where it is defined and push its sub's full name to the caller's symbol table, otherwise not. You can establish and check any other conditions you may need.

This way `Local` loads `Remote` only if the caller of `Local` requires a sub from `Remote`.

---

An example for the above description

**Local.pm**

```
package Local;

use warnings;
use strict;
use Exporter qw();

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(subLocal subRemote);

sub import {
    my $class = shift;

    my $re = qr/^(?:subRemote|other)/;
    my @local_exports  = grep { !/$re/ } @_;
    my @remote_exports = grep {  /$re/ } @_;   # check both

    if (@remote_exports) {   
        no strict 'refs';
        require Remote;
        foreach my $export (@remote_exports) 
        {   
            my $to_caller = caller() . '::' . $export;

            *{ $to_caller } = \&{ 'Remote::' . $export };
        }   
    }   

    @_ = ($class, @local_exports);  # set up @_ for goto
    goto &Exporter::import;         # switch to Exporter::import
}

sub subLocal {  print "subLocal() in ", __PACKAGE__, "\n" }

1;
```

The references to subs from `Remote` that are asked for are written to the caller's symbol table. Then our `import` is swapped by `Exporter::import` for exporting the rest of the symbols, from `Local`. For a note on goto [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40714498/4653379) for example. A few things are left out, firstly checks of received import lists.

There are no surprises with `main` and `Remote`

**main.pl**

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Local qw(subLocal subRemote);

subLocal();
subRemote();
```

**Remote.pm**

```
package Remote;   
use warnings;
use strict;
use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(subRemote);

sub subRemote { print "subRemote() in ", __PACKAGE__, "\n" }
```

with the output

```
subLocal() in Local
subRemote() in Remote
```

This accomplishes what is asked but it has to deal with rather specific details.

Comment: and pushing it into the caller's symbol table is done exactly how I'm currently doing it (i.e. `*subRemote  = \&Remote::subRemote;`) ?

Comment: @ardnew  Well, right -- but when you write your own `import` then you can do that _conditionally_.  Is that what you want?  Completed that statement in the answer.  Btw, you aren't exporting into the _caller_'s namespace..

Comment: @ardnew, No, that imports into the active namespace. It doesn't export into the caller's namespace. Besides, who do you think BEGIN's caller is?!

Comment: *"the caller of Local can require subRemote in its import list, but if it doesn't that the symbol then isn't pushed into the caller's namespace"* That sounds like the ordinary behaviour of `use` to me.

Comment: @ardnew: I wish you'd explain a little more. Everybody's guessing what you mean. It's beginning to sound like all you need is [`export_to_level`](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Exporter-5.72/lib/Exporter.pm#Exporting_Without_Using_Exporter%27s_import_Method)

Comment: @Borodin  Ugh, right, thank you.  I mean really to say that they need to implement their own `import` -- but I am not sure of what is needed in the question. (Ammended that sentence)

Comment: Are you thinking that the OP wants to import `Remote::subRemote` by writing `use Local 'subRemote'`? I'm still baffled.

Comment: @Borodin  That's my first quess, yes.  I am also thinking that they have in mind some other conditions, for which they need their own `import`. Perhaps not load from `Remote::` if not required by `main::`?  I am hoping for a clarification..

Comment: @zdim: Yeah, I suspect they're thinking that `Remote::subRemote` has to be imported as `Local::subRemote` before it can be imported again into `main`. Okay, then that's how object-oriented inheritance works. The OP should do it that way instead!

Comment: @Borodin  Right, that'd be a nice solutuion.  With my current understanding of the requirement, the import-way is simple as well, updated

Comment: @zdim: I think it's less simple to write. You have to check whether something in the import list is in `@Remote::EXPORT`, `@Remote::EXPORT_OK`, or `%Remote::EXPORT_TAGS`, and do the right thing in each case, handling collisions and symbols that aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: @Borodin  I do agree with that.  Just don't know whether they are up for inheritance & Co.

Comment: @zdim:  I think ikegami's solution proves my point! And I think the object-oriented route could be very simple as there's no need for any data in the object.

Comment: @ardnew  I updated the answer to more precisely state what I now think you need.

Comment: @ardnew  You got really nice answers, but I realize that I misread your first comment, of how to write to caller's symbol table.  There is far, far more to do than just this line, but the basics:  `my $to_caller = caller() . '::subRemote'; *{ $to_caller } = \&Remote::subRemote;`.  The RHS takes a reference to the sub, the LHS is the slot in the glob where it's written. If called from `main::` the LHS works out as `*main::subRemote = \&Remote::subRemote;`, but you need `caller` to be able to find that dynamically, and thus need the `{}` etc.  Again, just for completeness..